# NOT root user execute iptables shell by python

Tags: python, unix, root

I write some code to execute `iptables command` by python. This is code:

```
import subprocess

def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    if 'stdout' in kwargs:
        raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
    process = subprocess.Popen(stdout=subprocess.PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    output, unused_err = process.communicate()
    retcode = process.poll()
    if retcode:
        cmd = kwargs.get("args")
        if cmd is None:
            cmd = popenargs[0]
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    return output


def accept_port(port):
    try:
        cmd = r"iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport {0} -j ACCEPT && iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport {0} -j ACCEPT".format(port)
        output = check_output(cmd, shell=True)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    accept_port(1234)
```

Everything goes okay when I run the code by root user. But it fails when I use user `apache` to execute the above code. What should I do if I want to execute the code by user `apache` rather than `root`? I think `iptables command` must execute by `root user`. Could someone give some advice?? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this. Your server is now open to exploits.

The apache user is not for general use, its designed and restricted to be used by the Apache process.

Instead, using your web application trigger or schedule a task, and have a *different process* that is running as a *different, non-root user* read tasks from this queue and execute them.

Using `sudo` you can then only allow certain commands to be executed by this separate user. This way, your apache user is not privileged to run commands, and you are utilizing the security roles your operating system to isolate actions.

There is a reason why some commands are restricted for root users only :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sudo` command which allows any user to execute some `root` commands, check [here](http://www.ducea.com/2006/05/19/linux-tips-the-proper-way-to-allow-regular-users-to-run-commands-as-root/) for how to configure `sudo` for your use.

I would advise that you try https://unix.stackexchange.com/ if you have further questions on `root` executions.